# Ubuntu server 18.04 networking not getting dhcp or static not working

Tags: networking, server

I have setup LibreNMS on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM yesterday. (this is setup on HyperV on my windows 10 Pro laptop)  Everything was working fine yesterday.  It had a dynamic DHCP address.  I had been accessing it via SSH from the laptop locally using the DHCP address it had - a 192.168.x.x address.

Today I could not SSH into it.  Go into it via HyperV manager and sure enough no address showing up with `ifconfig` or `ifconfig -a`.

So I tried setting up static IP.  Still no go.  I have edited the `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file and setup static IP and nameservers. I will attach a picture as well. Not sure what to do at this point.  I am a Windows/Cisco guy but can get around on Ubuntu, just not a regular Ubuntu/Linux guy.

[image: screenshot-of-50-cloud-inityaml-file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working now.  Yesterday I had edited this file which I now no was a mistake:
`/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network`

I removed all configs from that file.  I then set the `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file back to DHCP and removed all configuration I had set in that file.  I ran sudo netplan generate.  That worked.  Then `sudo netplan apply`.  That also completed successfully.  So I was working again. I decided one more time to put in a static IP.  I was edited the `50-cloud-init.yaml` file again with the IP address and DNS that I wanted.  I ran `sudo netplan generate`, and `sudo netplan apply` and all is good!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Netplan is very picky about the config, remember to add all the appropriate colons and square brackets like behind 'nameservers' and around the static ip. Also remember to `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply`. This may also help: https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply AlexDude7.  I have not posted on this forum before.